Save button in Word VBA Editor saves "backup of backup of backup..." but not actual (active) Normal.dotm template
I have two buttons on my QAT that (1) save the attached template and (2) makes a copy of my Normal.dotm into a cloud folder (via a macro).
When creating or editing a macro, my typical habit is to either press Ctrl+S or click on the Save button in the editor window after even the tiniest changes. When I return to the document window, I press the two buttons on the QAT to ensure I have the latest changes saved to my Normal.dotm template. That has worked swimmingly for decades, until today.
The QAT buttons still work as expected, making copies and saving changes. But suddenly, when I press Ctrl+S or click on the Save button in the VBA editor window, the title bar indicates that it's saving a "Backup of Normal," and it also includes the name of the module I happen to be in at the time of saving.
It used to be if I closed out of Word at that point, after only saving within the editor window, changes made in the editor window were saved, but now they are not. The changes are still saved if I click on the "Save attached template" button on the QAT.
If I continue to press the Save button or press Ctrl+S in the editor window, it appends the file name in the title bar to "backup of backup," "backup of backup of backup," and on and on and on.
When I first open Word, with no documents open, I only see one template project listed in the editor window. When I create a new, blank document, I see the document and a References module and nothing else. After clicking the Save button, my template project name changes to "Normal (Backup of Normal)."
To my knowledge, I have not made any changes to my system or Word settings in the last 24 hours to trigger this behavior. I am running Win10 Pro (Version 22H2 OS Build 19045.4598) and the subscription version of Microsoft 365 (Version 2406, Build 17726.20126). This is a lone desktop, not attached to a network.
Thanks in advance for any insight into what is happening and how to fix it.
-Karen
UPDATE 7/17/24 I decided to see if I could solve the problem by deleting Normal.dotm and allowing Word to create a new template. After doing that, I created a macro (in the now-empty editor window), and when I pressed Ctrl+S in the editor window, a message popped up:
"You already have a file named Normal.dotm. Do you want to replace it with this one?"
In the decades that I have been using Ctrl+S or pressing the floppy disk to save, I have never seen these issues. I'm stumped!

Can't give you an answer but (a) the "References->Reference to Normal" reference is expected and (b) I'd at least check through your Addins and try disabling them one by one and see what happens (I recently noticed a slightly similar problem where Word is loading a normal.dotm from a temp file, and saving it back to that file "I.e. the wrong place) but I think it's probably a consequence of using MS's VSTO addin or some such.

Hmm, good thoughts, Jonsson. Thank you for the suggestion.
I've had the same add-ins for many years with no issues - Merriam-Webster, Dropbox for Office, PerfectIt, with no issues. When I checked just now, I did also see OneNote, which is something new and not something I installed purposely (MS must have snuck it in). I do know there is an issue with PerfectIt and the latest upgrade of Word that is being addressed by the PerfectIt folks, so there's that.
In any case, I just turned off all the add-ins, and the "backup of backup..." problem persists, sad to say.
